# Unable to save Figure in iPython Notebook throwing KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to save an eps file using savefig method of matplotlib, but I am getting an unusual exception (KeyError), and the message isn't actionable. Let me know what can be done thanks.

Regards,
Harsh

```
data_for_x_axis = [0,30,60,90,120,150,180]
data_for_y_axis = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0]
AX1 = plt.subplot(221)
plt.margins(1)
AX1.cla()
AX1.plot(data_for_x_axis, data_for_y_axis)  # some data 
AX1.set_xlim([0,180])
AX1.set_xticks([0,30,60,90,120,150,180])
AX1.set_yticks([0.5,1])
AX1.set_title(r'Normalized Stokes $I$')
AX1.set_xlabel('CQWP Rotation Angle (Degrees)')
AX1.set_ylabel(r'$I/I_{mean}$')
plt.savefig('.\\Plots\\4_ModDemod.eps', format='eps', dpi=2400)
```

This throws the following exception

```
xception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 256, in resize
    self._tkcanvas.create_image(
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2605, in draw
    artists.remove(spine)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2554, in _update_title_position
    # this happens for an empty bb
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 298, in _get_layout
    clean_line, self._fontproperties, ismath=ismath)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 206, in get_text_width_height_descent
    self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 3362, in parse
    font_output = fontset_class(prop, backend)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 883, in __init__
    self.cm_fallback = StixSansFonts(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 984, in __init__
    fullpath = findfont(name)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1238, in findfont
    rc_params)
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1270, in _findfont_cached
    + self.score_size(prop.get_size(), font.size))
  File "/Volumes/Elements/SSP Data Reduction/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1151, in score_weight
    w1 = weight1 if isinstance(weight1, Number) else weight_dict[weight1]
KeyError: '1'
```

Comment: The error has to do with a mathtext element which cannot be drawn. But you don't show that part in the question. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for the insight, yes, Indeed Mathtext is being used, I have updated that part in the question. Let me know what can be done to debug this.

Comment: What is the shortest code that reproduces this?

Comment: updated with random data, this fails in my system, ipython notebook, Using Mac Air, OS Mojave.

Comment: Does `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.text(.5,.5,r"$I$"); plt.draw()` fail with the same error?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes it does.

Comment: Might be worth editing the question then? Also including the matplotlib version in use. This will be very hard to debug. And I fear I cannot help from the outside, so you will need to wait for someone being able to reproduce this. You can also bring it up on the matplotlib issue tracker - though make sure to provide as much information as you can in such case.

Comment: Can you try a different backend than tk?  It’s strange you say you are doing this in the notebook, but the errors are all in tk.